# Tkinter - I can't disable the button widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

below you can see my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("300x200")
        self.root.title("Test")
        self.StartButton=ttk.Button(self.root, text="Start", command=self.Start)
        self.StartButton.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def Start(self):
        self.StartButton.config(state = "disable")
        #input()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.StartButton.config(state = "enable")

app = MainWindow()
```

when you click on the `OK` button, the script doesn't do nothing for 10 seconds, and during these seconds, the button should be disabled, but it doesn't happen. it happens only if you block the script using for example the `input()` function.

I really don't understand this weird behaviour. how can I solve this issue? it seems that the button is not able to disable itself duting the process, but the instruction to disable it, comes first than the process! so what is the issue?

Comment: It is because `time.sleep()` will block tkinter from updating widget state.  Use `after()` instead, or add `self.root.update()` after disabling the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options are `'disabled'` and `'normal`' (although `disable` also works, thanks to @Saad in the comments)
You also need to call `root.update()` for the changes to take place.

```
def Start(self):
    self.StartButton.config(state="disabled")
    self.root.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    self.StartButton.config(state="normal")
```

Alternatively (as also proposed in the comments by @acw1668), you should probably use `root.after` to reset your button after some time; this prevents the blocking effect of `sleep`, and makes the call to `root.update()` unnecessary:

```
def Start(self):
    self.StartButton.config(state="disabled")
    self.root.after(2000, lambda: self.StartButton.config(state="normal"))
```

Comment: We can use both `"disable"` and `"disabled"` to disable the state of a widget in Tkinter whereas to change the state back to normal only `"normal"` argument can be used. My guess is Tkinter checks the condition like so `if state in "disabled"` cuz `"dis"` also works to disable the button.

Comment: Noted, thank you @Saad, I did not know that! I edited the answer to reflect your point.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, your solution works, but I don't still understand what exactly blocks Tkinter to update itself. I mean, the `self.StartButton.config(state="disabled")` comes before the `time.sleep(2)` instruction, so why the state of the button stays active? for my future projects, how can I undertsand, before to run the code, if I have to use the `self.root.update()` instruction? is there a rule to keep in mind or not?

Comment: Probably the best rule to keep in mind, is to avoid using `time.sleep` with an event loop.